# How can I sync these two bootstrap carousels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

So, I'm trying to sync two Bootstrap 4 carousels, according to the image below:

[image]

I need both indicators and the arrow icons to show the content of the left and right sides simultaneously, but I can't seem to work it out. Can somebody help me?

I have no idea how to start coding, I'm a newbie at JavaScript and JQuery. And the idea here is to show a text and a video of a variety of subjects. I would really appreciate it if somebody could lay me a hand with this.

```html
<div class="categorias_content">
  <div class="left_side">
    <div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselSite" data-slide-to="5"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>Inteligência artificial que<br>cuida da sua saúde</h2>
          <p>Uma assistente virtual que avalia seu perfil e te dá sugestões de check-ups personalizados, alertas de consultas, medicamentos e dicas sobre como manter sua saúde em dia.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2>Medicamentos com até<br>60% de desconto</h2>
          <p>É só acessar o aplicativo pelo celular, pesquisar o medicamento e pegar o desconto em mais de 20.000 farmácias espalhadas pelo Brasil.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2>Agende consultas médicas<br>e exames com desconto.</h2>
          <p>Tenha acesso a um preço imbatível em consultas, exames, vacinas, procedimentos estéticos, homecare, cirurgias e muito mais.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2>Programa completo de nutrição e fitness</h2>
          <p>Emagrecer ou ganhar massa muscular ficou mais fácil.<br>No Clude você também tem um nutricionista e um personal trainer online na palma da sua mão.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2>Orientação médica e farmacêutica 24h</h2>
          <p>Esclareça dúvidas sobre sinais e sintomas diretamente com um médico sem precisar sair de casa.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2>Vídeo orientação médica<br>por apenas R$ 35<strong>*</strong></h2>
          <p>No Clude, você também pode conversar com um médico quando precisar através da vídeo orientação por um valor acessível. <em>*Valor de março/2020. Sujeito a alterações.</em></p>
        </div>

        <button class="btn-large--roxo">Saiba mais sobre o Clude Saúde</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right_side">
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselCelular" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <img src="./img/icons/left-arrow.svg" alt="">
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <div class="celular">
      <div class="celular_carousel">
        <div id="carouselCelular" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <h1>Darling</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <h1>Will</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <h1>This</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <h1>Finally</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <h1>Work?</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselCelular" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <img src="./img/icons/right-arrow.svg" alt="">
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is missing `javascript`, which is essential for such things. This article might help you with that (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp) also check the examples over there and js code after <script> tag (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_event_slide&stacked=h)

Comment: Just to clarify. The `HTML` that you link here is not a primary thing, you should add your own `js` file via `<script>` tag or add `bootstrap.js`(https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js) to the page.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need help from JS... We trigger the same control on one carousel based on the click of the similar control on the different carousel...

Inserted a landscape/portrait image on 2nd slide also :)

**Working snippet** below:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#demo2 .carousel-control-prev").click(() => {
    $("#demo .carousel-control-prev").trigger('click');
  });
  $("#demo2 .carousel-control-next").click(() => {
    $("#demo .carousel-control-next").trigger('click');
  });

  $("#d1one").click(() => {
    $("#d2one").trigger('click');
  });
  $("#d1two").click(() => {
    $("#d2two").trigger('click');
  });
  $("#d1three").click(() => {
    $("#d2three").trigger('click');
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

#demo,
#demo2 {
  width: 50vw;
}

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#demo .carousel-control-prev,
#demo .carousel-control-next,
#demo2 .carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li id='d1one' data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li id='d1two' data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li id='d1three' data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/Jumbo.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>

  </div>

  <div id="demo2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li id='d2one' data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> </li>
      <li id='d2two' data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li id='d2three' data-target="#demo2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo2" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo2" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>

  </div>
</body>
```