# How to sync/link 2 bootstrap 5 carousels

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have 2 Bootstrap 5 carousels (carousel-a & carousel-b) on one page and i wloud like them to be synced/linked to eachother.
I think this can be done with js but i'm not too familiar with js.
carousel-a looks like follows (carousel-b is identical):

```
<div id="carousel-a" class="carousel slide carousel-sync" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-pause="false" data-bs-interval="50000000">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel-a" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel-a" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel-a" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="assets/img/placeholder-1200x500.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="assets/img/placeholder-1200x500.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="assets/img/placeholder-1200x500.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel-a" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel-a" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Currently i have this but i cant seem to select my carousel, and i dont know why.

```
var carouselA = document.getElementById('carousel-a');
var carouselB = document.getElementById('carousel-b');

$(carouselA.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
    carouselB.carousel(event.to);
}));
```

Comment: Hi Steven, welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say the carousels should be sync'd/linked, do you mean that they should slide at the same time or, for example, slide a split second after each other. Or is it some kind of content that you want to link to both carousels? Just after a little clarification if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @CuteCodeRob i would like them to slide at the same time. they are placed on top of eachother and carousel-a (the top one) is gonna have controls and indicator whereas the bottom one (carousel-b) does not have controls or indicators (at least not visible ones). So for example if carousel-a moves one slide carousel-b needs to move one slide as well.

Comment: You're attempting to use jQuery methods when jQuery isn't involved. You'll need to use plain JavaScript and replicate what is being done with jQuery in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61436497/1264804).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully no JS is required. You can control each individual slide timing using `data-bs-interval="8000"` on each slide where 8000 is the number of seconds before the next slide comes into view.

For example. All of your slides could be set to 8 seconds as above or maybe your last slide is contact info and you want that to display for 12 seconds or something along those lines.

Each of your slides would look like this.

```
<div class="carousel-item active data-bs-interval="8000">
   <img src="assets/img/....." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i would also like to be abel to controll carousel-b with the controls of carousel-a.

Comment: To do that try giving both carousels the same `id`.  You would only need one set of arrows and buttons for the slides. One set of buttons controlling one `id` but two carousels with that `id`.

Comment: This does not work for me. I also tried to give the controls of carousel-a multiple data-bs-targets (`data-bs-target="#carousel-a,#carousel-b"`), but that also does not seem to work.

Comment: Check the documents at GetBootstrap mate. Don't worry, these little errors are just a challenge and most people in life will shirk a challenge. Here is a link to the Carousel page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - All derived from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/

Ensure the data-bs-interval are the same for both carousels

```
  // Grab your carousels
  const myCarouselOne = document.querySelector('#carouselOne')
  const myCarouselTwo = document.querySelector('#carouselTwo')

  // Get either the existing Bootstrap Carousel instance or create a new one
  const carouselOne = bootstrap.Carousel.getOrCreateInstance(myCarouselOne);
  const carouselTwo = bootstrap.Carousel.getOrCreateInstance(myCarouselTwo);

  // Grab your radio indicators, the previous and next buttons/arrows
  const indicatorsAll = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-indicators');
  const prevCarouselBtn = document.querySelector('.carousel-control-prev');
  const nextCarouselBtn = document.querySelector('.carousel-control-next');

  // Add event listeners to your indicators, previous and next buttons/arrows
  indicatorsAll.forEach( IndicatorBtn => IndicatorBtn.addEventListener("click", goToIndicatorCarousels));
  prevCarouselBtn.addEventListener('click', prevCarousels);
  nextCarouselBtn.addEventListener('click', nextCarousels);

  // Call the Bootstrap 'to' function for both Carousels to go to the indicator page that was clicked
  function goToIndicatorCarousels (e){
    let clickedIndicator = e.target.attributes[1].value;
    carouselOne.to(clickedIndicator);
    carouselTwo.to(clickedIndicator);
  }

  // Call the Bootstrap 'prev' function for both Carousels to go to the previous page
  function prevCarousels(){
    carouselOne.prev();
    carouselTwo.prev();
  }

  // Call the Bootstrap 'next' function for both Carousels to go to the next page
  function nextCarousels(){
    carouselOne.next();
    carouselTwo.next();
  }
```